# cost of (address) indirection to the same address many times (used in iterator)

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, indirection

If I use indirection a lot, but the target has the same address, will the cost of indirection become near-zero?

**Example :-**

```
class C{
    public: int database[100000];
    //other functions
};
class B{
    public: C* c=nullptr;
};
```

**First Scenario**

```
int main(){
    //--- first scenario (direct call) ---
    C c;
    for(int n=0;n<100000;n++){
         c.database[n]=43;
         //call some complex function about "c"
         //call some non-related function 
    }
}
```

**Second scenario**

```
int main() {
    //--- second scenario (indirection) ---
    C c;
    B b1;  
    b1.c=c; 
    for(int n=0;n<100000;n++){
         b1.c->database[n]=43;
         //call some complex function about "c", but call in "b1.c" form
         //call some non-related function 
    }
}
```

Would both cases cost (nearly) the same?
How much possibility that it will be optimized out to be nearly the same?

I believe cost of indirection is low (because no cache miss  for `c`),
 but I don't know whether there is a **base** cost (`b1.c->` vs `c.`)?
(I am new for C++)

In real case, `B` is an iterator, and `C` is the related data-structure.

Comment: You'll have to measure it and find out.

Comment: Why not profile the code and see if you get a difference?

Comment: Measure it in Release mode. I would expect that there is no difference in optimized code.

Comment: If I profile, I can measure only 1 case.  I think some solid concept might be worth more than a lot of experiment.   (no?)

Comment: premature optimization

Comment: Yes sir!  From the pressure of many experts, I will try it out. Thank.  As  drescherjm adviced (above and below comments) : **1.** release mode   **2.** do something with the array after filling

Comment: Make sure you use a high resolution timer. I recommend c++11 std::chrono. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration And make sure the loop does not get optimized out. Meaning you probably have to do something with the array after filling.